# How to send json and file to an Ajax action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to use AJAX to send JSON data and a file via formData to an action in MVC. I tried to do that with ajax:

```
$('#btn_send_form').on('click', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var Products = [];
    var prItems = $('#sellerTbl').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < $(prItems).length ; i++) {
        Products.push({
            "Product_Id": $(prItems).eq(i).attr('data-id'),
            "ProductCode": $(prItems).eq(i).children().eq(1).text().trim(),
            "Qty": $(prItems).eq(i).children().eq(2).text().trim(),
            "Price": $(prItems).eq(i).children().eq(3).text().trim().replace(/,/g, '')
        });
    }
    var Cheques = [];
    var chequeItems = $('#checkTbl').children();
    for (var i = 0; i < $(chequeItems).length ; i++) {
        Cheques.push({
            "DueDate": $(chequeItems).eq(i).children().eq(0).text().trim(),
            "Amount": $(chequeItems).eq(i).children().eq(1).text().trim().replace(/,/g, ''),
        });
    }
    var productBuy = {
            "Seller_Id": $('#lst_seller').val(),
            "SubSeller_Id": $('#lst_subseller').val(),
            "Products": Products,
            "PreFactorId": $('#facNo').val(),
            "PreFactorPrice": $('#facPrice').val().replace(/,/g, ''),
            "TaxPercent": $('#facTax').val(),
            "PayCash": $('#facNaghd').val().replace(/,/g, ''),
            "Cheques": Cheques
    }
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("productBuy",
        new Blob([JSON.stringify(productBuy)], {
            type: "application/json;charset=utf-8" 
        }))
    formData.append('Image', $('#facScan')[0].files[0]);


    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("AddBuyProductRequest", "Buy")",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",

        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                alert();
            } 
        },

    });
})
```

**To this action:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddBuyProductRequest(AddProductBuyRequestVM productBuy, HttpPostedFileBase Image, string returnUrl)
        {
// some code ...
        }
```

This action get Image but productBuy is always null.

And this is the view-model :

```
public class AddProductBuyRequestVM
    { 
        public int Seller_Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SubSeller_Id { get; set; }
        public string PreFactorId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> PreFactorPrice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> TaxPercent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> PayCash { get; set; }
        public List<ProductDetailsInBuy> Products { get; set; }
        public List<ProductCheque> Cheques { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I get both of the view-model(productBuy) and Image together via Ajax ?

Comment: There is something wrong with your view if you think you need to do this. You arrays of `Products` and `Cheques` are based on non editable data that was sent from the controller to the view so why in the world would you send the same data back to the controller again (just get it again in the POST method).

Comment: And the fact that you have a `.replace()` to remove commas from a `long` also makes no sense. If you have generated you view correctly, then you can delete everything before the `ajax({` line and simply use `data: new FormData($('form').get(0)),`

Comment: @StephenMuecke because Products and Cheques are dynamics and generate in client side by javascript.

Comment: Then do it correctly and generate form controls for them